# Linked SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, distributed-databases, kerberos

I'm trying to link 2 SQL Servers (2008 and 2005). I have tried it via the GUI and scripts, and having no luck. I have problems trying to to query through it with access. As I'm not the Admin of the network, I'm working hard on investigating how to success on this but I always receive a message telling me that the user "../Anonymous Logon" is not allowed to connect.

After some research, I believe this is a problem related to Kerberos that is not transferring my credentials to the machine I'm trying to link to. I'm using NT Authentication and I have no possibility to use/create SQL Authentication logins.

I've already sent a mail to my network Admin to see if we are able to use Kerberos delegation here.

What would be the next steps to find out what is happening to my configs and why this isn't working?

Thanks in advance and, as this is my first question, hello everybody!

Answer (score 5):

You need to talk to your network admin to see if Kerberos delegation is enabled, and whether it's constrained or not (if it's enabled and unconstrained that is a *massive* potential security risk, just by the by). If it is constrained then you need to register a SPN (Service Principal Name) for your SQL Server and bind your SQL Server account service to that SPN in your AD configuration. http://windowsitpro.com/security/kerberos-delegation-and-troubleshooting has an explanation of it from the point of view of a web server that wants to pass user credentials to a SQL Server (whereas what we're doing here is passing user credentials from SQL Server to a second SQL Server, but the principle holds).

If Kerberos delegation is *not* enabled and your network admin refuses to budge on that (and you can't create SQL logins), then you're out of luck and need to escalate via your management (or think of an alternative to using linked servers), since NTLM authentication (which is the fallback if Kerberos isn't enabled) doesn't work with linked servers.